# Distinct attribute value from Global Secondary Index in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

How do we achieve the similar functionality of distinct keyword from SQL in Amazon DynamoDB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve distinct values from the hash key - DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992227/retrieve-distinct-values-from-the-hash-key-dynamodb)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DynamoDB Query distinct attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230463/dynamodb-query-distinct-attribute-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

dyanamo db is not support this kind of functionality, but you can achieve this in some ways (client side, lambda on dynamodb stream the updates another table with distinct values..)

you can find a good answer here: [Retrieve distinct values from the hash key - DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992227/retrieve-distinct-values-from-the-hash-key-dynamodb)