# DynamoDB Query distinct attribute values

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query DynamoDB and get a result similar to `select distinct(address) from ...` in SQL.

I know DynamoDB is a document-oriented DB and maybe I need to change the data structure.

I'm trying to avoid getting all the data first and filtering later.

My data looks like this:

| Attribute | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| ID | String |
| Var1 | Map |
| VarN | Map |
| Address | String |

So I want to get the distinct addresses in the entire table.

How it's the best way to do it?

Comment: If you're going to need this query a lot, then you might want to introduce an additional table AddressCount that contains (unique) Address, ID, and Count. Configure DynamoDB Streams on the original table and update the AddressCount table using a Lambda function to atomically insert, increment/decrement Count, delete when items are inserted/modified/deleted on the original table. Then a simple scan of that table will give you, minimally, the unique addresses.

Comment: I will be executing the query once a week maybe two. Its not much I think, but the numbers of address increase every day. So I am considering your approach, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You'll need to `Scan` the entire table (you can use the `ProjectionExpression` or `AttributesToGet` options to ask just for the "Address" attribute, but anyway you'll pay for scanning the entire contents of the table).

If you need to do this scan often, you can add a secondary-index which *projects* only the keys and the "Address" attribute, to make it cheaper to scan. But unfortunately, using a GSI whose partition key is the "Address" **does not** give you an ability to **eliminate duplicates**: Each partition will still contain a list of duplicate items, and unfortunately there is no way to just listing the different partition keys in an index - `Scan`ing the index will give you the same partition key multiple times, as many items there are in this partition.

Comment: I was afraid to confirm this. You gave me the idea to add a second index, in order to reduce cost. Another way I think, is create a new table, but the cost of develop a secondary process to insert / upsert and maintain the secondary table It's not worthy. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to maintain a second table just remember to handle case of item **deletion** - you can't just delete the address from the second table, because it might be used by another item. One thing you can do to solve this is to keep a "reference count" attribute on each address in the second table, decrement it instead of deleting the address, and when scanning the second table filter out address with reference count 0. It's all easy to do in DynamoDB - but not really concurrency-safe because two different tables are involved :-(

Answer (score 0):

In the same table you can put a hardcode value in partition key i.e. "address" and in sort key put the address unique key. Your table will look like below:

[image]