# AWS DynamoDB list distinct ID

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am developing something with nodejs and I have a table on DynamoDB. Therefore, I am using aws-sdk for nodejs to work with these two things.

Here is an example. ID and name are the combined key to the table.

```
ID    name   otherData
----------------------
1     Matt   123
1     Mary   1234
2     Mary   2312
4     Mary    3123
4     Pet    3123
```

What I want is to get a list of distinct ID. So, the expected output is

```
ID = [1, 2, 4]
```

How to do this?

Comment: Hey @ykn checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992227/retrieve-distinct-values-from-the-hash-key-dynamodb].

Comment: So, there are no api call that can achieve this?

Comment: I think you have to Perform a Scan with the appropriate ```ScanFilter```. check here `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/count-distinct-items-example.html`

Comment: I reached http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/what-is.html with your link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve distinct values from the hash key - DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992227/retrieve-distinct-values-from-the-hash-key-dynamodb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Do a DynamoDB scan to get all (non-unique) ID values. The ProjectionExpression limits the result attributes returned, in this case to ID only. Note this doesn't make your scan any faster. When you execute the scan you will get a JSON object back containing your results. You can use JMES to get the ID array (data.Items.ID).

2) Make the array unique in your nodejs code (e.g. using the ArrNoDupe code function below)

```
var params = {
 ProjectionExpression: "ID",
 TableName: "YOUR_TABLE"
};

ddb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
      console.log(ArrNoDupe(data.Items.ID));
    });
  }
});

function ArrNoDupe(a) {
    var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        temp[a[i]] = true;
    var r = [];
    for (var k in temp)
        r.push(k);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I think I accept this as the answer. It seems that there are no way that can run this in aws side. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer, apparently we still have to scan the entire table and pay for it